# Textnow API Errors when logging in through a script

Tags: json, api, promise

When trying to log into textnow through an API using the correct username and password, the following error occurs:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 401 Unauthorized
at _response.transport.request.then (E:\nodejs\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:193:21)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:19732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.            
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without
a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
(rejection id: 2)
```

Here's a look at the code from the API  that I'm using:

```
module.exports.textnowLogin = (email, password) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let json = { "password": password, "username": email };
   let queryEndpoint = "sessions?client_type=TN_ANDROID";
   let signature = md5(`${tnSignatureKey}POST${queryEndpoint}${JSON.stringify(json)}`);

    snekfetch.post(`https://api.textnow.me/api2.0/${queryEndpoint}&signature=${signature}`)
    .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .send(json)
    .then((result) => {
      return resolve(result.body);
    }).catch(reject);
  });
};
```

Here's a look at how I use this method in my js file:

```
const textNow = require('textnow-api');
textNow.login(username, password).then(client => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.username}`);
});`
```

This definitely has to be a server side issue, no? Something must be going wrong on Textnow's end. What can I do to circumvent this?

EDIT: `const snekfetch = require("snekfetch"),
        md5 = require("md5"),
            tnSignatureKey = "f8ab2ceca9163724b6d126aea9620339";`

Where did this key originate from? Perhaps if a new one was generated then the authorization error would be solved?

As a side note, another potential issue could be the client_type being set to ANDROID, and I am trying to use an iOS account to login. However, whenever I try using an Android account to log in instead, I get a 400 Bad Request, like Textnow does not recognize the account's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other errors in the code, but the first mistake is the creation of an extra promise.  Here's a version of the code that solves that and should either work or be simpler to debug...

```
module.exports.textnowLogin = (email, password) => {
  let json = { "password": password, "username": email };
  let queryEndpoint = "sessions?client_type=TN_ANDROID";
  let signature = md5(`${tnSignatureKey}POST${queryEndpoint}${JSON.stringify(json)}`);

  let url = `https://api.textnow.me/api2.0/${queryEndpoint}&signature=${signature}`;
  return snekfetch.post(url).set("Content-Type", "application/json").send(json).then(result => {
    return result.body;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that code looks much more succinct and readable. I do not have much experience with JavaScript but I will try debugging and come back here with results on what may be going on, as the 401 Unauthorized error is still occurring.

Comment: @BisquickQuick a 401 error is progress of the sort. It is different from the OP error, and probably related to the server rejecting the request for security reasons (maybe related to the formation of that signature.  I think the code structure in the OP was preventing you from seeing (and therefore debugging) the real error which is between your code and the server's expectation

Comment: Im thinking that the tnSignatureKey being used could be causing the problem. The variable is set at the top, perhaps the key provided is no longer allowed or recognized on Textnow's end. I will edit the post with the key provided in the API